# Mongodb can't use parameter as update field filter key?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want build a simple function which can update (`upsert`) a document by `collection name, field key, field value, updateData`

example:

```
function updateDB(tableName, id, rowInfo, checkfield, callback) {
db.collection(tableName, function (err, collection) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {

        console.log(checkfield);
        collection.update({ checkfield: id }, rowInfo, { upsert: true }, function (err, objects) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
                callback(false);
            } else {
                //  console.log(objects);
                callback(true);
            }
        });
    }
});}
```

However when I use parameter as field filter in update query it always inserts new data an does not update the document. Example:

```
collection.update({ checkfield: id }.....
```

But when I change the field filter to `realFieldName` it works correctly. Example:

```
collection.update({ 'realFieldName': id }....
```

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should code it like:

```
var filter = {};
filter[checkfield] = id;
collection.update(filter, ...);
```

define an object like `{ checkfield: id }`, `checkfield` is regarded as an identifier NOT a variable.

for details, please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

> An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or
>   anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty
>   string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript
>   identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen,
>   or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square
>   bracket notation. This notation is also very useful when property
>   names are to be dynamically determined (when the property name is not
>   determined until runtime)

Comment: @maxyen you are welcome